# Using asyncio recursively gather links from sub-directories in a webpage

Tags: python, recursion, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to write a program that gets all the links on webpage, even from sub-directories. I have this working with the requests package, but it is slow when you have to get links from a lot of sub-directories. Here is my working code that takes about 4 minutes to gather all the links from https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/sea-surface-temperature-optimum-interpolation/v2.1/access/avhrr/.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(base_url):
    req = requests.get(base_url)
    return req.text if (req.status_code == 200) else ''

def get_links(html_page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")  # removed "html.parser"
    regex = r'(.nc$)|(/$)'
    links = [f"{base_url}{link.get('href')}" for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(regex)})]
    return links

def get_sub_dirs(links):
    sub_dirs = [link for link in links if re.search(r'/$', link)]
    return sub_dirs 

def get_files(links):
    file_links = [link for link in links if re.search(r'.nc$', link)]
    return file_links
    
def main(base_url):
    files = []
    html_page = get_html(base_url)
    links = get_links(html_page)
    sub_dirs = get_sub_dirs(links)
    base_files = get_files(links)
    files.append(base_files)

    for sub in sub_dirs:
        sub_files = main(sub)
        files.append(sub_files)
        
    return files

# Run programe
base_url = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/sea-surface-temperature-optimum-interpolation/v2.1/access/avhrr/'
files = main(base_url)
```

I think the bottleneck in the code is the `get_html()` function, it takes a few seconds to get back the html. I think this code can be optimized using async functions, but I am struggling to make this work. Here is my attempt at an async version of the code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 
async def get_html_async(base_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.get(base_url) as resp:
            return await resp.text() if (resp.status == 200) else ''
        

def get_links(html_page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")  # removed "html.parser"
    regex = r'(.nc$)|(/$)'
    links = [f"{base_url}{link.get('href')}" for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(regex)})]
    return links

def get_sub_dirs(links):
    sub_dirs = [link for link in links if re.search(r'/$', link)]
    return sub_dirs 

def get_files(links):
    file_links = [link for link in links if re.search(r'.nc$', link)]
    return file_links
  
async def get_tasks(session):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text() if (resp.status == 200) else ''
  
    
async def main(base_url):
    files = []
    html_page = await asyncio.gather(get_html_async(base_url))
    links = get_links(html_page[0])
    sub_dirs = get_sub_dirs(links)
    base_files = get_files(links)
    files.append(base_files)

    for sub in sub_dirs:
        sub_files = await asyncio.gather(main(sub))
        files.append(sub_files)
        
    return files

# Run program
base_url = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/sea-surface-temperature-optimum-interpolation/v2.1/access/avhrr/'
files = asyncio.gather(main(base_url))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `asyncio.gather()` the way you do, you are running your requests sequentially as before. `asyncio.gather()` is taking multiple iterables as arguments to run them concurrently. There is no point in calling `asyncio.gather()` with just one awaitable, since then you could simply await it. By creating all coros in `main()` without awaiting them and then passing them all to `asyncio.gather()` you get a significant speed-up:

```py
# some minor fixes added
import asyncio
import re
from itertools import chain

import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


async def get_html_async(base_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
        connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False) # I got ssl errors on my machine
    ) as client:
        async with client.get(base_url) as resp:
            return await resp.text() if (resp.status == 200) else ""


def get_links(html_page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")  # removed "html.parser"
    regex = r"(.nc$)|(/$)"
    links = [
        f"{base_url}{link.get('href')}"
        for link in soup.findAll("a", attrs={"href": re.compile(regex)})
    ]
    return links


def get_sub_dirs(links):
    sub_dirs = [link for link in links if re.search(r"/$", link)]
    return sub_dirs


def get_files(links):
    file_links = [link for link in links if re.search(r".nc$", link)]
    return file_links


async def main(base_url):
    files = []
    html_page = await get_html_async(base_url)
    links = get_links(html_page) # removed indexing 'html_page[0]'
    sub_dirs = get_sub_dirs(links)
    base_files = get_files(links)
    files.extend(base_files) # extend list to get "cleaner" output, keep using 'append' if your downstream code requires it

    coros = [main(sub) for sub in sub_dirs] # create all requests
    new_files = await asyncio.gather(*coros) #  run all requests concurrently
    files.extend(chain(*new_files)) # again, add to list as needed

    return files


# Run program
base_url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/sea-surface-temperature-optimum-interpolation/v2.1/access/avhrr/"
files = asyncio.run(main(base_url)) # or simply 'await main(base_url)' in IPython
print(files)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @thisisalsomypassword, this works like a charm! And the speed-up achieved is amazing! from 4 minutes to about 12 seconds